# img url in CSS - .NET MVC wants a controller

Tags: .net

I am trying to use standard CSS with statements like 'background: url('../images/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right;'

Upon running I get Visual Studio messages indicating no controller found. How can I tell the framework to resolve image URLs directly and literally without requiring a controller?

Comment: @Downvoter: While I agree that some more information about the directory structure would help avoiding guesses, I don't think that the question is bad enough to justify a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative paths don't work very well with MVC.  The reason is that /Home and /Home/Index (for  example) might point to the same page, so there's no way to construct a relative path that works for both.

The solution is to use absolute paths like "/Content/Images/img.png" or "http://mydomain.com/Content/Images/img.png" (that is, at least, for static resources like .css files that don't allow you to use dynamic syntax).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require a controller if it is in the contents folder. Where is your CSS located? Images are relative to the CSS location and not the document where the CSS is located.

I suspect that you may be going back too much in the URL with the `..` (parent), which then generates an URL such as `yourhost.com/images/sort_asc.png` which would trigger the framework to look for a "images" controller.

Try for instance:

```
background: url('images/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right;
```

(assuming that the CSS is directly in the `Contents` folder and there is a folder `images` with your bitmaps in the `Contents` folder as well)